# Applying Style To RichTextBlock using Range Information in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, richtextblock

This code snippet comes from `RichEditBox` style application,

```
Document.Selection.SetRange(paragraphStartIndex, paragraphStartIndex + data.Text.Length);
Document.Selection.CharacterFormat.Strikethrough = FormatEffect.On;
```

However, can we do similar things with a `RichTextBlock`?

I know that I can add a `<run>` or a `<Span>` and add style information to these elements, but is there any way to grab the whole `RichTextBlock` content and apply style to a range of text within it?

Answer (score 1):

`RichTextBlock` and `RichEditBox` are rich text-related controls, but they are very different in display.

The process of RichEditBox displaying rich text is like drawing on paper, because it carries the modified function, so there is a complete `Document` as a carrier.

`RichTextBlock` is not responsible for modification, it is only responsible for display, so it is more like building blocks. `RichTextBlock` has a lot of display elements to render different visual effects, but they are independent of each other. You can't set effects for a certain character. You can only set the effect for the entire block (such as `Paragraph`).

When you select text in the `RichTextBlock`, you can get the parent element of the currently selected text point through `RichTextBlock.SelectionStart.Parent` or `RichTextBlock.SelectionEnd.Parent`, and set the effect.

Best regards.